# Difference between base_stuff and stuff in sales_flat_order in magento

Tags: magento

I noticed that there are some fields like base_shipping_invoiced and then there is stuff like shipping_invoiced in sales_flat_order.

I am wondering what is the difference between them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

magento supports `multiple currencies` and lets you set a `base currency` so in case if you are using multiple currencies then `base_stuff will be in your base currency` and `stuff will be in converted currency`

every time you implement some price related stuff you should follow this approach and ensure that proper values would be used