# Magento sales_flat_order_item table

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

There are four price columns in magento 1.6 CE sales_flat_order_item table:

```
price, base_price, original_price and base_original_price,
```

what the difference between them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between base_stuff and stuff in sales_flat_order in magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186646/difference-between-base-stuff-and-stuff-in-sales-flat-order-in-magento)

Comment: and what about original_price column?

Comment: think baby think :) original_price, discounted_price, special_price etc you name it :) the idea is the same base_original -> original

Comment: I cant find columns "discounted_price, special_price" in my sales_flat_order_item table, but when I do order on special priced product in four columns "price, base_price, original_price and base_original_price" I have same value, my special price. I understand this currency thing with base_ columns, but can't understand your comment about original_price column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name does imply the relationship: original_price is where you started, price is where you end up.

If you edit the order on the backend to apply custom pricing, you will see the difference in this table. I have attached a screenshot to show where I adjust the last order that came in to have a lower price (444 vs 1750).

[image: Screenshot of different values in the fields]